# 2012 Mac pro on High Sierra 10.13.6 doesn't play DVDs anymore. Can this be remedied by updating driver?

Tags: high-sierra, dvd

So my macbook is getting on but still functioning well for everyday purposes. However the other day I took out a stack of arty DVDs from the local library and not one of them is recognized by mac, which honestly has probably not tried playing a DVD for years. I read somewhere this might be down to iDVD not working on High Sierra. Either way, has anyone else experienced this and knows of something I could do to view DVDs again without splashing out on a new machine? Software or driver etc, ideas welcome

Comment: The DVD player internal mechanism and most likely the lens is probably full of [cruft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruft) from years of disuse. This [lens cleaner](https://www.amazon.com/Maxell-190059-Thunderon-Equipment-Enhancement/dp/B00000JPPI) will clean off the lens quite well, but if the internal mechanism is crufty, your best bet is to get an [external DVD player](https://www.amazon.com/LG-Electronics-Portable-External-GP65NB60/dp/B00ODDE33U) which is relatively inexpensive.

Answer (score 1):

iDVD *was* always OS X version dependent and was software to create DVDs.  It was removed in High Sierra.

As a player, you can use DVD Player which is included in High Sierra.

If DVD Player doesn't work, you may have a hardware issue.